# Suitecrm/Sugarcrm ..How to assign an array in template file?

Tags: crm, sugarcrm, suitecrm

Here the controller view file SuiteCRM/modules/Contacts/views/view.detail.php

```
<?php
if(!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');   

require_once('include/MVC/View/views/view.detail.php');
require_once('api/soap_api.php');

class ContactsViewDetail extends ViewDetail
{
    /**
     * @see SugarView::display()
     *
     * We are overridding the display method to manipulate the portal information.
     * If portal is not enabled then don't show the portal fields.
     */
    public function display(){
        global $sugar_config;

        $aop_portal_enabled = !empty($sugar_config['aop']['enable_portal']) && !empty($sugar_config['aop']['enable_aop']);
        //echo '<pre>===='; print_r($aop_portal_enabled); exit; 
        $this->ss->assign("AOP_PORTAL_ENABLED", $aop_portal_enabled);

        require_once('modules/AOS_PDF_Templates/formLetter.php');
        formLetter::DVPopupHtml('Contacts');

        $admin = new Administration();
        $obj         = new AirtelUserInfo();
        $res         = $obj->test();

        $sql = 'select * from contacts';

        //$result = $this->db->query($sql,true," Error filling in additional detail fields: ");

        // Get the id and the name.
        //$row = $this->db->fetchByAssoc($result);

        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($sql); exit;


        $this->ss->assign("res", $res);

        $admin->retrieveSettings();
        if(isset($admin->settings['portal_on']) && $admin->settings['portal_on']) {
            $this->ss->assign("PORTAL_ENABLED", true);
        }
        parent::display();
    }
}
```

here the tpl file path 
SuiteCRM/cache/modules/Contacts/DetailView.tpl

```
<script language="javascript">
{literal}
SUGAR.util.doWhen(function(){
    return $("#contentTable").length == 0;
}, SUGAR.themes.actionMenu);
{/literal}
</script>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" id="">
<tr>
<td class="buttons" align="left" NOWRAP width="80%">
<div class="actionsContainer">
<form action="index.php" method="post" name="DetailView" id="formDetailView">
<input type="hidden" name="module" value="{$module}">
<input type="hidden" name="record" value="{$fields.id.value}">
<input type="hidden" name="return_action">
<input type="hidden" name="return_module">
<input type="hidden" name="return_id">
<input type="hidden" name="module_tab">
<input type="hidden" name="isDuplicate" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="offset" value="{$offset}">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="EditView">
<input type="hidden" name="sugar_body_only">
</form>
<ul id="detail_header_action_menu" class="clickMenu fancymenu" ><li class="sugar_action_button" >{if $bean->aclAccess("edit")}<input title="{$APP.LBL_EDIT_BUTTON_TITLE}" accessKey="{$APP.LBL_EDIT_BUTTON_KEY}" class="button primary" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView'); _form.return_module.value='Contacts'; _form.return_action.value='DetailView'; _form.return_id.value='{$id}'; _form.action.value='EditView';SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);" type="button" name="Edit" id="edit_button" value="{$APP.LBL_EDIT_BUTTON_LABEL}">{/if} <ul id class="subnav" ><li>{if $bean->aclAccess("edit")}<input title="{$APP.LBL_DUPLICATE_BUTTON_TITLE}" accessKey="{$APP.LBL_DUPLICATE_BUTTON_KEY}" class="button" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView'); _form.return_module.value='Contacts'; _form.return_action.value='DetailView'; _form.isDuplicate.value=true; _form.action.value='EditView'; _form.return_id.value='{$id}';SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);" type="button" name="Duplicate" value="{$APP.LBL_DUPLICATE_BUTTON_LABEL}" id="duplicate_button">{/if} </li><li>{if $bean->aclAccess("delete")}<input title="{$APP.LBL_DELETE_BUTTON_TITLE}" accessKey="{$APP.LBL_DELETE_BUTTON_KEY}" class="button" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView'); _form.return_module.value='Contacts'; _form.return_action.value='ListView'; _form.action.value='Delete'; if(confirm('{$APP.NTC_DELETE_CONFIRMATION}')) SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);" type="submit" name="Delete" value="{$APP.LBL_DELETE_BUTTON_LABEL}" id="delete_button">{/if} </li><li>{if $bean->aclAccess("edit") && $bean->aclAccess("delete")}<input title="{$APP.LBL_DUP_MERGE}" class="button" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView'); _form.return_module.value='Contacts'; _form.return_action.value='DetailView'; _form.return_id.value='{$id}'; _form.action.value='Step1'; _form.module.value='MergeRecords';SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);" type="button" name="Merge" value="{$APP.LBL_DUP_MERGE}" id="merge_duplicate_button">{/if} </li><li><input class="button" id="manage_subscriptions_button" title="{$APP.LBL_MANAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS}" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView');_form.return_module.value='Contacts'; _form.return_action.value='DetailView'; _form.return_id.value='{$fields.id.value}'; _form.action.value='Subscriptions'; _form.module.value='Campaigns'; _form.module_tab.value='Contacts';_form.submit();" name="Manage Subscriptions" type="button" value="{$APP.LBL_MANAGE_SUBSCRIPTIONS}"/></li><li><input type="button" class="button" onClick="showPopup();" value="{$APP.LBL_GENERATE_LETTER}"/></li><li>{if !$fields.joomla_account_id.value && $AOP_PORTAL_ENABLED}<input title="{$MOD.LBL_CREATE_PORTAL_USER}" class="button" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView');_form.action.value='createPortalUser';_form.submit();" name="buttonCreatePortalUser" id="createPortalUser_button" type="button" value="{$MOD.LBL_CREATE_PORTAL_USER}"/>{/if}</li><li>{if $fields.joomla_account_id.value && !$fields.portal_account_disabled.value && $AOP_PORTAL_ENABLED}<input title="{$MOD.LBL_DISABLE_PORTAL_USER}" class="button" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView');_form.action.value='disablePortalUser';_form.submit();" name="buttonDisablePortalUser" id="disablePortalUser_button" type="button" value="{$MOD.LBL_DISABLE_PORTAL_USER}"/>{/if}</li><li>{if $fields.joomla_account_id.value && $fields.portal_account_disabled.value && $AOP_PORTAL_ENABLED}<input title="{$MOD.LBL_ENABLE_PORTAL_USER}" class="button" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('formDetailView');_form.action.value='enablePortalUser';_form.submit();" name="buttonENablePortalUser" id="enablePortalUser_button" type="button" value="{$MOD.LBL_ENABLE_PORTAL_USER}"/>{/if}</li><li>{if $bean->aclAccess("detail")}{if !empty($fields.id.value) && $isAuditEnabled}<input id="btn_view_change_log" title="{$APP.LNK_VIEW_CHANGE_LOG}" class="button" onclick='open_popup("Audit", "600", "400", "&record={$fields.id.value}&module_name=Contacts", true, false,  {ldelim} "call_back_function":"set_return","form_name":"EditView","field_to_name_array":[] {rdelim} ); return false;' type="button" value="{$APP.LNK_VIEW_CHANGE_LOG}">{/if}{/if}</li></ul></li></ul>
</div>
</td>
```

Comment: What you want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I want to know how to data assign to tpl file from database

Comment: I hope you got the answer which has been posted by Daniel. As you have given the cache tpl file path. And if you are trying to add html code in tpl file then its not good solution. it will affect the performance. Instead you write the custom code in custom/modules/contact/view.detail.php file inside display function.

Comment: I am new in Suitecrm and recently started it is difficult to find model view controller

Answer (score 2):

In your view you will need to assign your variable in the display method like following:

`$myArray = array(1000, 1001, 1002);
$this->ss->assign("myArray", $myArray);`

Then you will need to edit the smarty template:

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$myArray item=foo}
    <li>{$foo}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```